# What should be the env variables in the docker compose file of kafka connect to export jmx metrics

Tags: docker, jmx, apache-kafka-connect

PFB the compose file config I have used

```
version: '2'
services:
  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.0
    hostname: kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafk_server_host_name:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false - 
      Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 - 
      Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8000"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars'
    volumes:
      - ./libs:/etc/kafka-connect/jars/
```

After starting kafka connect in docker when I try to connect to localhost 8000 using jconsole I am getting the following error:

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
```

Please help in troubleshooting the error. I am not sure if the env variable I have used is the right one.

I have one more question: does exposing jmx port in kafka provides metrics for kafka connect also or should get metrics from kafka and kafka connect individually?

Comment: Have a look at https://rmoff.net/2018/09/17/accessing-kafka-docker-containers-jmx-from-host/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in resource provided by Robin Moffatt

https://rmoff.net/2018/09/17/accessing-kafka-docker-containers-jmx-from-host/

i mentioned the two variables KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME and KAFKA_JMX_PORT and used 9010 port specifically since other ports where giving me the jrmf error given in the question